# Prove that the sequence of vectors $(\vec{b_1}, \vec{b_2}, \vec{b_3})$ is linearly dependent.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I'm troubled with the following problem and would like your help.

---

Let $(\vec{a_1}, \vec{a_2}, \vec{a_3})$ be a Sequence of linearly independent Vectors in an arbitrary Vector Space. We consider the vectors

$$\vec{b_1} = \vec{a_1} + 2\vec{a_2} - \vec{a_3}$$
$$\vec{b_2} = 2\vec{a_1} + 2\vec{a_2} - \vec{a_3}$$
$$\vec{b_3} = 4\vec{a_1} + 2\vec{a_2} - \vec{a_3}$$

Prove that the sequence of vectors $(\vec{b_1}, \vec{b_2}, \vec{b_3})$ is linearly **dependent**.

---

I'm really troubled by this question because for me $(\vec{b_1}, \vec{b_2}, \vec{b_3})$ seem to be linearly independent, not dependent, don't you agree ?

If $$\vec{a_1} = (1,0,0)^T$$ $$\vec{a_2} = (0,1,0)^T$$ $$\vec{a_3} = (0,0,1)^T$$ then $$\vec{b_1} = (1,2,-1)^T$$ $$\vec{b_2} = (2,2,-1)^T$$ $$\vec{b_3} = (4,2,-1)^T$$ which clearly aren't linearly dependent. Is there something I'm missing ?

Comment: Feel free to comment if anything is unclear

Comment: "Which *clearly* aren't linearly dependent"? Why is that?

Comment: Calculate the determinant of the matrix obtained by stacking the $b$ vectors. It is $0$, so they are dependent. Note that you can find out that $\vec b_3=-2\vec b_1+3\vec b_2$.

Comment: @Andrei Generally, one round of row reduction is faster than calculating determinants :)

Comment: @TedShifrin I only try that for 2 by 2 or 3 by 3 matrices

Comment: Sure, but bad advice to give people just starting out :)

Comment: @Andrei How did you find out so quickly that $\vec b_3=-2\vec b_1+3\vec b_2$ ? I also get 0 for the determinant, didn't thought it could be "that" simple. I thought that because we are talking about vectors, and not element of vectors, we shouldn't proceed like that. Like $a_n, b_n$ are not elements in this case, but vectors on their own, was really confused about that. Thanks for the support

Comment: @TedShifrin After row reduction I get $(1 0 0, 0 -2 1, 0 0 0)$, did you get that too ? So we can conclude that they are dependent because $b_3$ is a free variable, is that correct ?

Comment: @TedShifrin Also, if we exclude $b_3$, then $b_1$ and $b_2$ are in that case independent of each others right ?

Comment: Write $\alpha \vec b_1+\beta\vec b_2=\vec b_3$. Then write for each component. The last two equations are identical, $\alpha+\beta=1$. For the first component $\alpha+2\beta=4$. Subtracting the first equation from the second yields $\beta=3$, so $\alpha=-2$.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Note that a nontrivial solution of the homogeneous system $Ax=0$ tells you a nontrivial linear combination of the *columns* of $A$ that gives the $0$-vector. So if you put the coefficients in as columns, rather than as rows, you will recover that information.  wengen, in the future, be careful when you're tempted to say "clearly." :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your support Andrei and Ted Shifrin